# Uniqueness of a submodule

Tags: ring-theory, modules, noncommutative-algebra

Suppose I want to show that $\mathbb{C}[X]$ is the unique simple $A_1$-submodule of $\mathbb{C}[X,X^{-1}]$, where $A_1 = A_1(\mathbb{C})$ is the first Weyl Algebra.

It is not difficult to show it is simple. Moreover, I read that if $\mathbb{C}[X] \subseteq A_1 * \alpha$, for any $0 \neq \alpha \in \mathbb{C}[X,X^{-1}] / \mathbb{C}[X]$, then uniqueness follows. Although I am finding it difficult to understand why this is the case. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have added this into the question.

Comment: When you wrote $0 \neq \alpha \in \mathbb{C}[X,X^{-1}] / \mathbb{C}[X]$ did you actually mean $0 \neq \alpha \in \mathbb{C}[X,X^{-1}] \setminus \mathbb{C}[X]$? Because then it would make sense.  If there were another simple submodule, it'd be cyclic, and another distinct simple submodule could not possibly contain this one.

Comment: By the way I'm not familiar with this module. How does the weyl algebra act on $\mathbb C[X,X^{-1}]$?  Just as formal differentiation on polynomials?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any $f\in \mathbb{C}[X,X^{-1}]$, there is some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $X^nf\in \mathbb{C}[X]$.  So, if $f$ is nonzero, the $A_1$-submodule generated by $f$ contains a nonzero element of $\mathbb{C}[X]$, and thus contains all of $\mathbb{C}[X]$ since $\mathbb{C}[X]$ is simple.  So, every nonzero submodule of $\mathbb{C}[X,X^{-1}]$ contains $\mathbb{C}[X]$, and thus such a submodule cannot be simple unless it is equal to $\mathbb{C}[X]$.